# react-redux: actions do not change the store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm building a react app with redux and I have a problem.

I have a component connected to the redux store and even though I dispatch actions those actions are not received from the reducer thus the state won't change.

Here's the code of the component:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import { setOrderFilter } from "store/filters";

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        filters: state.entities.filters,
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    setOrderFilter,
};

function Filters(props) {
    const { order } = props.filters;

    console.log(setOrderFilter({test: 1}) 
    // {type: "filters/setOrderFilter", payload: {…}}
    // payload: {test: 1}
    // type: "filters/setOrderFilter"

    const handleOrder = (event) => {
        setOrderFilter({ order: event.target.value });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <label>
                Date order:
                <select value={order} onChange={(e) => handleOrder(e)}>
                    <option value="ascending">ascending</option>
                    <option value="descending">descending</option>
                </select>
            </label>
        </div>
    );
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Filters);
```

Here's the `filters.js` file in the store:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const slice = createSlice({
    name: "filters",
    initialState: {
        order: "descending",
    },
    reducers: {
        setOrderFilter: (state, action) => {
            console.log("here");
            state.order = action.payload;
        },
    },
});

export const { setOrderFilter } = slice.actions;

export default slice.reducer;
```

Everything looks fine, even `console.log` the action `setOrderFilter` yields the correct result, but when I change the select in the UI, no action is dispatched and the value doesn't change...
the `console.log` inside the reducer is never printed.

The store is configured with an api middleware to handle async code:

```
import axios from "axios";
import * as actions from "store/api";

import getBaseUrl from "helpers/getApiUrl";

const api = ({ dispatch }) => (next) => async (action) => {
    console.log(action)
    if (action.type !== actions.apiCallBegan.type) return next(action);

    ....
};

export default api;
```

The calls from other entities are printed and visible in the middleware, the one from `filters` are not even printed there.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the handleOrder function.

```
const handleOrder = (event) => {
    setOrderFilter({ order: event.target.value });
};
```

You have to use the connected `setOrderFilter`. That is in the component's props.

```
const handleOrder = (event) => {
    props.setOrderFilter({ order: event.target.value });
};
```

It's an easy mistake to make when using the mapDispatchToProps shorthand. There is a function in scope called `setOrderFilter`, but when you use that, you will just create the action object, but it will not be dispatched to redux.

Answer (score 0):

I think its the variables names. Try this:

```
state.order = action.order;
```

Comment: I'm not sure where should I add that line, can you please be more specific?

Comment: in filters.js when defining the reducer

Comment: @asma action has 2 thigns `its type` and `payload`, so you can only access passed data 
 as `payload` so that is correct code there

Comment: try instead of console.log("here"), consoling console.log(action), and see how it responds

Answer (score 0):

if you are using redux-toolkit you can directly use hooks.

> Here seems like you are `just calling` the action, `it's not enough` but you also `need to dispatch action as well`. in your case, it's not even reaching a reducer as you are `NOT dispatching it`that is the issue.

Try this, It should fix your issue.

```
import React, { useCallback } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { setOrderFilter } from "store/filters";

function Filters(props) {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const handleOrder = useCallback ((event) => {
        // you actually need to dispatch action not just call it
        dispatch(setOrderFilter({ order: event.target.value }));
    }, []);

    // ... other code
```

I hope this will solve your issue

> If you want a solution in your way then use this

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import { setOrderFilter } from "store/filters";

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  applyOrderFilter: (filterData) => dispatch(setOrderFilter(filterData))
});

// in your component

function Filters(props) {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const handleOrder = useCallback ((event) => {
        // you can call that prop method
        props.applyOrderFilter({ order: event.target.value }));
    }, []);

    // ... other code
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Filters);
```

if any doubt please comment.